# How to get all the requestmapping of all controllers?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

I created many `controllers` having each their requestmapping specified in order for them to be identified in the app :

[image]

```
package com.ambre.hib.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    ...

}

package com.ambre.hib.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ajax")
public class AjaxController {

    ...

}
```

So how to get programmatically all the value of the requestmappings of all controllers in the project ? I want to get something like a list containing for example "/" , "/ajax".

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using **Google Guava** and **Java Reflection API**.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>19.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) includes a class [ClassPath](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/17.0/api/docs/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html) with three methods to scan for top level classes, in that you can use `getTopLevelClasses(String packageName)`

Refer this example code.

```
public void getClassOfPackage(String packagenom) {

    final ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread()
            .getContextClassLoader();
    try {

        ClassPath classpath = ClassPath.from(loader); // scans the class path used by classloader
        for (ClassPath.ClassInfo classInfo : classpath.getTopLevelClasses(packagenom)) {
         if(!classInfo.getSimpleName().endsWith("_")){
            System.out.println(classInfo.getSimpleName());
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Below code will print all @RequestMapping from **a single controller**, you can update this code.

```
 Class clazz = Class.forName("com.abc.cbe.rest.controller.MyController"); // or list of controllers, //you can iterate that list
    for(Method method :clazz.getMethods()){
         for(Annotation annotation :method.getDeclaredAnnotations()){
             if(annotation.toString().contains("RequestMapping"))
            System.out.println("Annotation is..."+ annotation.toString());
     }
     }
```

Comment: the `getClassOfPackage` method does not work : there is no output in console ! I already added the dependency in pom.xml and updated the project.

Comment: I tested that code before sharing here, did you debug?

Comment: what lines should I debug ?

Comment: Hahaha, I am not that guy ;-)

Comment: your last code about `Class.forName` does not give result for the controller , it only outputs for actions inside a controller !